# Dynamic XQuery using saxon:evaluate not working in Oxygen with an XPath 3.1 type expression?

Tags: saxon, oxygenxml, xpath-3.1, xquery-3.1

I'm interested in using the saxon:evaluate in an XQuery (using the Oxygen XML Editor 24.0) and wanted to see it working in a very simple example using XPath 3.1 type expression so I can select a value from a parsed JSON object (using Saxon-EE XQuery 9.9). However in doing so I get an error returned reporting Static error in XPath expression supplied to saxon:evaluate: The XPath parser is not configured to allow use of XPath 3.1 syntax?

I tried the below:

```
let $rawJ :=
                    <jroot><![CDATA[
                                 {
                                    "siam_envelope": 
                                    {
                                        "protocol_version": "1"
                                    }
                                    }]]>
                    </jroot>
let $j := parse-json($rawJ)
let $expression := "$p1?siam_envelope?protocol_version"
let $result := saxon:evaluate($expression, $j)

return $result
```

I expected this to return the value "1" but instead it reported the "Static error in XPath expression supplied to saxon:evaluate: The XPath parser is not configured to allow use of XPath 3.1 syntax"

Presumably, this is because I'm using a map type XPath which is only supported in XPath 3.1. However, since the error reports "not configured" then I'm holding some hope that there's some configuration I can apply to get this working? If not, does anyone in this community know how to run a dynamic XPath 3.1 type expression in XQuery? Surely this must be possible?

Thanks in advance for any useful suggestions!

Comment: Do you need or want to do that in that rather outdated oXygen 24 version with Saxon 9.9? Or are you working with a supported Saxon version like 11 or 12, independently of oXygen?

Comment: I think the current state is that `saxon:evaluate` is not supported in Saxon 12 as Saxonica wanted you to use standard XSLT/XQuery/XPath features like using `fn:transform` with `xsl:evaluate`. However, the latest change is to reinstate the functions in Saxon 12 https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/6094, so in the next release they should be back. I don't know about oXygen 24.

Answer (score 0):

Without using Saxon specific extensions, you can use `fn:transform` with `xsl:evaluate`:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'adaptive';
declare option output:indent 'yes';

declare function local:eval($expression as xs:string, $context-item as item()?) as item()* {
  transform(
    map {
      'stylesheet-node' : <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0" 
        xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
        <xsl:function name="mf:eval" as="item()*" visibility="public">
          <xsl:param name="expression" as="xs:string"/>
          <xsl:param name="context-item" as="item()?"/>
          <xsl:evaluate xpath="$expression" context-item="$context-item"/>
        </xsl:function>
      </xsl:stylesheet>,
      'initial-function' : QName('http://example.com/mf', 'eval'),
      'function-params': [$expression, $context-item],
      'delivery-format': 'raw'
    }
  )?output
};

let $rawJ :=
                    <jroot><![CDATA[
                                 {
                                    "siam_envelope": 
                                    {
                                        "protocol_version": "1"
                                    }
                                    }]]>
                    </jroot>
let $j := parse-json($rawJ)
let $expression := "?siam_envelope?protocol_version"
let $result := local:eval($expression, $j)
 
return $result
```

That should work with any XQuery 3.1 implementation supporting `fn:transform` and `xsl:evaluate`, so in the case of Saxon for HE that means 10 or later or for PE or EE I think 9.8 or later.

Comment: That's very helpful and it works in my Oxgen version. Thank you Martin! The reason I'm using Oxygen 24 is because I need to test XSLT/XQuery in Saxon-EE 9.9 as this is the parser of my integration engine